# django prefetch_related many queries

Tags: django, django-models

Django 1.7

I have a model:

```
   class Model(models.Model):
       tags = models.ManyToManyField(..)
```

When I do `Model.objects.prefetch_related()....` it results in many individual queries being issued to fetch the tags, one for each model.

I'd expect 2 queries to happen: 1 to fetch the models, another to fetch the tags for all models.

How to do that?

**EDITED**:

I'm using a raw query like `Model.objects.prefetch_related('tags').raw_query(..)`

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a field name to prefetch:

```
Model.objects.prefetch_related('tags')
```

If you use the `queryset.raw()` method then `prefetch_related()` logic doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, which version of django you use?  In django 1.7.4 your code throws the exception: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'raw_query'`

Comment: May be you use `raw()` (not `raw_query()`)? If this case `prefetch_related()` will not work. Show the full code, may be it can be some other solution instead of `raw()` call.